# how to deliberately trigger a StackOverflowException without using recursion?

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, stack-overflow

I was told that every method has a stack the size of 1mb.
So I assumed that initializing 256 integer values in one method will cause a StackOverflowException. I tried that in code, but no exception was thrown.

So, how to deliberately trigger a StackOverflowException without using recursion?

Comment: 256 * 4 bytes = 1kb, not 1mb

Comment: 256 integers is = 256 * 4 bytes = 1024 bytes = 1 kb, not 1 MB. Therefor, you would need 256000 integers. And I wouldn't even try to write a code with 256000 declarations. (edit: and Marc Gravells is always faster) :)

Comment: It would be pretty bad if you could only use `256 * 4` bytes of memory in a single method... On the other hand, it would probably help keep methods small! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll add another method :-)

```
unsafe struct FixedBufferExample
{
    public fixed byte Buffer[128 * 1024]; // This is a fixed buffer.
}
```

Now this structure is 128kb :-) If you declare a local variable (of a method that doesn't use yield or async) of type `FixedBufferExample` it should use 128kb of stack. You can use up your stack quite quickly.

Answer (score 18):

use

```
throw new StackOverflowException ();
```

Comment: +1. Always use the simplest approach that gets the result you are after? :)

Answer (score 8):

`stackalloc` is probably the easiest way (assuming you want *the runtime* to throw the error, rather than yourself):

```
    unsafe void Boom()
    {
        int* data = stackalloc int[512 * 1024]; // 2MB
    }
```

Comment: is there any difference if used on 64 Bit system ? Is the stack bigger ?